# Vue - accessing data within arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am trying to populate a table using data from API used to populate other tables. How do I access and assign the data to the fields in the table?

I have assigned placement to fields so it is not similar to previous table. however the data would not show up in the table.

```
    fields: {
        staff_id: {
            label: 'Staff ID',
            sortable: false
         },
        staff_name: {
             label: 'Staff Name',
            sortable: true
        },
        unit_name: {
            label: 'Unit',
            sortable: true
        },
        acc_activation: {
            label: 'App status',
            sortable: true
        },
        Actions: {}
    };

    placement: {
        unit_name: {
            label: 'Unit Name',
            sortable: false
        },
        division: {
            label: 'Division',
            sortable: false
        },
        start_date: {
            label: 'Start Date',
            sortable: false
        },
        end_date: {
            label: 'End Date',
            sortable: false
        },
        status_type: {
            label: 'Status',
            sortable: true
        }
    }
```

the data for placement table is located in an array within another array. how do i access it to display on the table?

Comment: You have an object there not an array.   You use object notation.  If `placement` is in your component's data object then you would access `unit_name` properties with `this.placement.unitname.label`

Comment: what i meant was, the data for placement table is in an array within an array. how can i access that data in the array to assign to the fields?

Comment: Ok. There is not enough code shown above to determine how your table component utilizes the data passed to it.  Are you using some library for your tables or are you simply looping (using v-for) through your array and  rendering rows to your table or what?

Comment: the data is from API, which is in array form

Comment: "data": [
{
"staff": "hafiz ",
"placement": [
{
"placement_id": 397,
}]

I am trying to assign placement_id data to the placement table under unit_name field.

Comment: Still not sure I understand what you need to access.   The format of your data in the example vs the comment is different.   If you need to access placement_id in your comment example you would use something like `data[0].placement[0].placement_id` https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/8na27b5k/10/

Comment: The data in your example shows two objects of objects. There are no arrays in your example. If you need to access objects, based on what you've shown you would do something like `fields.staff_id.label`.